# Detect Changes to Environment Variables

Tags: python

So, I'm using Python and unittest to test the behavior of another program. By and large, this is working fine. But one of the behaviors I need to test is whether the other program correctly sets and unsets certain environment variables. The order of events is: Python test script starts, that Python script starts the program to be tested, the Python script invokes a command on the other program that should set or unset an environment variable, Python script attempts to detect that environment variable so the test can pass or fail. Now, I can confirm through manual testing that the environment variable *is* being set correctly, but I can't get Python to pick up on that. The Python script never seems capable of seeing any updates to the environment variables. Is there some way around this?

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: this is going to be os dependant ... what os are you using? ... for example if you are using a linux variant you may be able to do something like `cat /proc/<pid>/environ` or on windows you maybe able to inspect the registry\

Answer (score 0):

if your using [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) to test for variables:

> This mapping is captured the first time the os module is imported,
>   typically during Python startup as part of processing site.py. Changes
>   to the environment made after this time are not reflected in
>   os.environ, except for changes made by modifying os.environ directly.